# Cuda 7.5 and VS requirements

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

I'm trying to use graphic card (RTX 2060) with tensorflow using Cuda.
But i'm unable to do so.
Cuda 7.5 seems to need Visual Studio 2013 and i'm unable to find it in order to install Cuda (using Windows 10).

I tried to get it from "https://my.visualstudio.com/" and got a 403 error.

Did i miss something ? Any of you know a way to get it ?

First time here, thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Compute Capability **is NOT same as** CUDA version.

For RTX 2060, compute capability 7.5 is required.

Compute capabilities among graphic cards:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA

At least CUDA SDK 10.0 is required to be able to use your graphic card.

Moreover, CUDA SDK 10.0 can be used with VS 2012 up to 2017.

However, if you want use with the latest VS, say it VS 2019, you need more later CUDA SDK.

For example, you can use CUDA SDK 11.5,

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

with VS 2019, it should work properly.